# Designing a proof assistant around Cubical

Tags: cubical-type-theory, design, cubical-agda

As far as I know, Agda is currently the only "widely popular" theorem prover to have somewhat good HoTT support via it's CubicalTT mode. Now, I understand what has slowed down the addition of CubicalTT to other proof assistants, like Coq - in the paraphrased words of one of the Coq devs, "all of the 5 experts on CubicalTT are working on Agda."

My question, then, is that given that it is somewhat difficult to integrate cubical into an existing theorem prover, what can be done to *design one around* cubical? Obviously there are the modifications to the core theory, but I'm sure there are other areas where a language could be modified to best allow the use of HoTT. I've only seen a few theorem provers that have been designed around cubical, and non of them seem to have very active communities, so I thought I would see if there was anyone here who had any knowledge on the subject.

Comment: I bet at least one of the five experts is reading this question.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, Well, if they are, I'd like to make it very clear that I harbor no ill will - after all, I'd rather have one working implementation than four broken ones ;)

Comment: I am sure no ill will was presumed. I was just hoping to provoke one of the experts into answering the question.

Comment: Another difficulty when trying to extend Coq's type theory that you do not have in Agda are tactics. In Agda, if you extend the type-checker with a new feature, it is just as usable as the other features of the language. In Coq, even if a feature is well-supported at kernel/type-checker level, if the tactics are not aware of its existence it will be near unusable. This happened for instance with strict propositions, that were supported in the kernel but not well integrated in higher layers, meaning that if you wanted to use them you had to resort to rather non-idiomatic low level proofs.

Comment: I will just push back a little bit on the implicit assumption that cubical type theory is the only way to have "good HoTT support".  There are very extensive libraries of HoTT code in Coq such as UniMath and Coq-HoTT.  Cubical type theory is only one kind of HoTT.